# Find the subgroups of order 4?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have the following abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_2\times \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. I know every element, except $(0,0,0)$ generates a cyclic subgroup of order 2.

Is there a systematic way I can find all subgroups of order 4 without having to list them all out?

Comment: They are kernels of maps to $\Bbb Z_2$.

Comment: Pretty much. If you want to merely *count* how many there are, there is a trick to do that instead.

Comment: Note that you are trying to find all codimension-1 subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_2^3$, so you get them via the nonzero functionals, just like how you did with subgroups of order 2.  But that is really not different from listing them all out.

Comment: What does a subgroup of order $4$ look like? Which elements generate such a group? How do you find generators in your original group? How do you eliminate duplicates? Each of these steps is pretty easy and together they give you a quick count of the number of subgroups.

Answer (score 2):

Every such subgroup $H$ is isomorphic to Klein's $4$-group, namely it is of the form $H=\{e,a,b,a+b\}$, where $a,b$ are chosen among the $7$ elements of order $2$ of $G:=\mathbb{Z/2Z}\times\mathbb{Z/2Z}\times\mathbb{Z/2Z}$. So, the number of distinct subgroups of order $4$ of $G$ is $1/6\cdot7\cdot(7-1)=7$.

---

**Edit**. In general, let (additive notation) $I_G:=\{a_i\in G\mid 2a_i=e_G\}$, where $G$ is any abelian group. Then, the subgroups of $G$ isomorphic to Klein's $4$-group are of the form $K_{ij}=\{e_G,a_i,a_j,a_i+a_j\mid a_i,a_j\in I_G, \space1\le i<j\le |I_G|\}$. Note that, once set $a_k:=a_i+a_j\in I_G$, we may have either:

- $k<i<j$, then $K_{ij}=K_{ki}=K_{kj}$, or
- $i<k<j$, then $K_{ij}=K_{ik}=K_{kj}$, or
- $i<j<k$, then $K_{ij}=K_{ik}=K_{jk}$.

Therefore, the number of distinct subgroups of $G$ isomorphic to Klein's $4$-group is given by:$n_K:=\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{|I_G|^2-|I_G|}{2}=\frac{1}{6}\cdot |I_G|\cdot(|I_G|-1)$, whence the special case above for $|I_G|=7$.

Answer (score 1):

There are seven subgroups of order $2$, one for each nonzero element.  For each of those subgroups you can consider the canonical projection to the quotient group $\Bbb Z_2$.  The kernel of each such projection is then a subgroup of order $4$.